# Get actual content within element with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have some HTML which looks like this:

```
<textarea>&lt;p&gt;</textarea>
```

If I do something like this in Python:

```
import bs4
doc = bs4.BeautifulSoup("<textarea>&lt;p&gt;</textarea>", "html.parser")
print(doc.select("textarea")[0].string)
```

The result `<p>` is printed. This is categorically false and incredibly misleading, the actual contents of this element do not include the `<` or `>` characters at all.

How can I get the **actual** content inside an element, as I'd see if I'd manually `curl`'d the page? Can I turn off this feature?

---

I've also tried this:

```
>>> for c in doc.select("textarea")[0].children:
...   print(c)
... 
<p>
```

Comment: No `.string` is the **rendered** content in the tag. The **encoding** is `&lt;` but in reality it means you want to write `<`. Mind that `bs` aims to give a **semantical** interpretation to the XML/HTML file.

Comment: I don't want the rendered content. I'm aware the encoding is `&lt;`. I'm checking to see if user content has been properly escaped, there's quite a significant difference between a `<script>` and a `&lt;script&gt;`! How can I retrieve the *actual* content?

Comment: yes, but in the case of `<script>`, it will **not** be shown in the `.string` attribute: then you have to iterate over the tag its (tag-)children.

Comment: See edit, I've tried iterating over the children. Am I doing that wrong?

Comment: yes, that is a *text* child. If you print `type(c)`, you will see that it generates `bs4.element.NavigableString`. If it is a tag, like `<p></p>`, it will be a `bs4.element.Tag`.

Comment: Okay, that's somewhat useful. But how do I print out the raw (un-decoded) content of a `NavigableString` instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the [default documented behavior of the `bs4` package](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#output-formatters):

> If you give Beautiful Soup a document that contains HTML entities like
>   “&lquot;”, they’ll be converted to Unicode characters. If you then
>   convert the document to a string, the Unicode characters will be
>   encoded as UTF-8. You won’t get the HTML entities back. By default,
>   the only characters that are escaped upon output are bare ampersands
>   and angle brackets. These get turned into `&amp;`, `&lt;`, and `&gt;`,
>   so that Beautiful Soup doesn’t inadvertently generate invalid HTML or
>   XML.

You can though get your entities back as is on output:

```
In [1]: import bs4

In [2]: doc = bs4.BeautifulSoup("<textarea>&lt;p&gt;</textarea>", "html.parser")

In [3]: textarea = doc.select_one("textarea")

In [4]: textarea.unwrap()
Out[4]: <textarea></textarea>

In [5]: print(doc)
&lt;p&gt;
```